# Logic Gates and Truth Tables

Tags: javascript, html

I have been working on this for a while and I don't know why its not working properly. It seems that no matter what value I put into the input boxes it comes with the same value when it is not meant to change depending on the true or false values. It should follow the rules of truth tables with AND, OR, and XOR statements. I haven't done any of the XOR code yet because I want to solve this issue first. Any ideas why it keeps giving me the same output no matter what?

```js
var binary = document.getElementById("binary").value;
var binarytwo = document.getElementById("binarytwo").value;

function truefalse(){
  if (binary == 1 && binarytwo == 1){
    document.getElementById("and").innerHTML = "1 or TRUE"
  }else{
    document.getElementById("and").innerHTML = "0 or FALSE"
  }

  if (binary == 1 || binarytwo == 1){
      document.getElementById("or").innerHTML = "1 or TRUE"
  }else if (binary == 1 || binarytwo == 0){
      document.getElementById("or").innerHTML = "1 or TRUE"
  }else if (binary == 0 || binarytwo == 1){
      document.getElementById("or").innerHTML = "1 or TRUE"
  }else{
    document.getElementById("or").innerHTML = "0 or FALSE"
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<h1>Logic Gates</h1>
<br>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Write two Binary Values</h1>
<br>
  <input id = "binary">Type a 0 or 1 here
  <br>
  <input id = "binarytwo">Type a 0 or 1 here
  <br>
  <button onclick = "truefalse()">"Click Here to get the Statements"</button>
  <p id="or">OR Statement</p>
  <p id="and">AND Statement</p>
  <p id="xor">XOR Statement</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from the correct observation that you're only using the initial inputs, your logic also isn't correct.

The 'OR' field will always be "1 or TRUE" as written.
Remember that using the javascript OR, the two pipes: ||
will only check the first part if it return true.

Your code:

```
if (binary == 1 || binarytwo == 1){
      document.getElementById("or").innerHTML = "1 or TRUE"
  }else if (binary == 1 || binarytwo == 0){
      document.getElementById("or").innerHTML = "1 or TRUE"
  }else if (binary == 0 || binarytwo == 1){
      document.getElementById("or").innerHTML = "1 or TRUE"
  }
```

Look what happens here. Let's assume binary equals 1:
`if (binary == 1 || binarytwo == 1) {` is true, since `binary == 1` and the rest is skipped. So `else if (binary == 1 || binarytwo == 0){` will never be executed.

If binary = 0, then the first 3 will never be executed and only `}else if (binary == 0 || binarytwo == 1){` will get checked. This will always succeed, sicne binary is always 0 when this gets triggered. The check that `binarytwo == 1` never happens, because the || has already succeeded for `binary == 0`

So you're more looking for logic like this:

```
if (binary == 1 && binarytwo == 1) console.log('both are TRUE: AND');
else if (binary == 1 || binarytwo == 1) console.log('one is true: OR');
else console.log('both are FALSE');
```

If you ahve to say 'AND' as well when both are false, you can just fold the last `else` into the first:

```
if ( (binary == 1 && binarytwo == 1) || (binary == 0 && binarytwo == 0) ) console.log('AND');
else console.log('OR');
```

Answer (score 1):

You're getting the values only once. When you call the function you don't get the actual values again. Just move the getElementById values to the function.
You also din't include the xor part. 
This is the full thing:

```js
function truefalse(){
var binary = document.getElementById("binary").value;
var binarytwo = document.getElementById("binarytwo").value;
  if (binary == 1 && binarytwo == 1){
    document.getElementById("and").innerHTML = "1 or TRUE"
  }else{
    document.getElementById("and").innerHTML = "0 or FALSE"
  }

  if (binary == 1 || binarytwo == 1){
      document.getElementById("or").innerHTML = "1 or TRUE"
  }else if (binary == 1 || binarytwo == 0){
      document.getElementById("or").innerHTML = "1 or TRUE"
  }else if (binary == 0 || binarytwo == 1){
      document.getElementById("or").innerHTML = "1 or TRUE"
  }else{
    document.getElementById("or").innerHTML = "0 or FALSE"
  }

  if (binary == 1 && binarytwo == 1){
      document.getElementById("xor").innerHTML = "0 or FALSE"
  }else if (binary == 1 && binarytwo == 0){
      document.getElementById("xor").innerHTML = "1 or TRUE"
  }else if (binary == 0 && binarytwo == 1){
      document.getElementById("or").innerHTML = "1 or TRUE"
  }else{
    document.getElementById("xor").innerHTML = "0 or FALSE"
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<h1>Logic Gates</h1>
<br>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Write two Binary Values</h1>
<br>
  <input id = "binary">Type a 0 or 1 here
  <br>
  <input id = "binarytwo">Type a 0 or 1 here
  <br>
  <button onclick = "truefalse()">"Click Here to get the Statements"</button>
  <p id="or">OR Statement</p>
  <p id="and">AND Statement</p>
  <p id="xor">XOR Statement</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

but you can make this code much simpler like this:

```
function truefalse() {
  var binary = Number(document.getElementById("binary").value);
  var binarytwo = Number(document.getElementById("binarytwo").value);

  document.getElementById("and").innerHTML = !! (binary && binarytwo);
  document.getElementById("or").innerHTML =  !! (binary || binarytwo);
  document.getElementById("xor").innerHTML = !! ( ( binary && !binarytwo ) || ( !binary && binarytwo ) );
}
```

See it working here: https://jsfiddle.net/b9wf977v/4/

!! is a simple javascript "trick" to convert a numeric value to boolean.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't changing your binary codes.
Right now your binary values are scoped outside, only pouplated when the program initialises, but the values are never changed when you push the button.

You need to move them into the function so the binary values reflect the values from the forms when the function is called.

What happens in your code:

- read form values(empty)
- assign form values to binary variables(empty)

  ---
- push button
- calculate(empty is empty)
- display result

  ---
- push button
- calculate(empty is empty)
- display result

What happens in the below code is:

- push button
- read form values
- assign form values to binary variables (value, value)
- calculate(value, value = something)
- display result

  ---
- push button
- read form values
- assign form values to binary variables(value, value)
- calculate(value, value = something)
- display result

  ---

```js
function truefalse(){

  //Inside the function loop

  var binary = document.getElementById("binary").value;
  var binarytwo = document.getElementById("binarytwo").value;

  if (binary == 1 && binarytwo == 1){
    document.getElementById("and").innerHTML = "1 or TRUE"
  }else{
    document.getElementById("and").innerHTML = "0 or FALSE"
  }

  if (binary == 1 || binarytwo == 1){
      document.getElementById("or").innerHTML = "1 or TRUE"
  }else if (binary == 1 || binarytwo == 0){
      document.getElementById("or").innerHTML = "1 or TRUE"
  }else if (binary == 0 || binarytwo == 1){
      document.getElementById("or").innerHTML = "1 or TRUE"
  }else{
    document.getElementById("or").innerHTML = "0 or FALSE"
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<h1>Logic Gates</h1>
<br>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Write two Binary Values</h1>
<br>
  <input id = "binary">Type a 0 or 1 here
  <br>
  <input id = "binarytwo">Type a 0 or 1 here
  <br>
  <button onclick = "truefalse()">"Click Here to get the Statements"</button>
  <p id="or">OR Statement</p>
  <p id="and">AND Statement</p>
  <p id="xor">XOR Statement</p>
  </body>
</html>
```